# how is possible to become root without having the password and only a ssh login?

Tags: security, debian

I am having a problem, I have one server, I have my root account, but some other co worker has an ssh login, still... I have no so much experience and I dont know what I could do to block him to become super user or execute some jobs only with that user, what do I need to block to avoid that?

I am using Debian Linux.

Comment: To be able to do so would be a ***huge*** security risk...

Comment: yes, and im trying to avoid that, I installed a root kit hunter, but I dont know if are other ways (for some reasons i can't delete his user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the root password secret and remove him from the sudoers file. Also make sure to use a kernel not affected by this new exploit: http://fucksheep.org/~sd/warez/semtex.c ;)

Comment: If i am not using sudo, only su- is possible he could make me some damage through his user?

Comment: if he don't know the root password he can't - but you have to be careful that all your chmods are set cirrectly. maybe you want to lock him up inside a chroot?

Comment: thats a pretty nice idea! thank you